# How to construct complex MySQL query with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql

My cognitive abilities and MySQL-skills have reached their limits with that MySQL-query I need to do and I am looking for some help.

My "job"-table looks like this:

```
| jobunique | jobtypeunique | joblat | joblng | jobbusiness | jobpayed | jobfixedstartdate | jobstartdate | jobfixedenddate | jobenddate | jobcreatedtimestamp
|    1      |         4     |  23.99 | 18.34  |      1      |    1     |         0         | 2019-04-06   |        0        | 2019-05-11 | 2019-04-05 12:22:02
|    2      |         2     |  31.34 | 11.89  |      1      |    0     |         0         | 2019-03-02   |        0        | 2019-04-01 | 2019-04-05 12:23:21
|    3      |         7     |  42.31 | 14.34  |      0      |    1     |         0         | 0000-00-00   |        0        | 0000-00-00 | 2019-04-05 12:23:44
|    4      |         7     |  60.99 | 55.67  |      0      |    1     |         1         | 2019-04-06   |        0        | 0000-00-00 | 2019-04-05 12:26:14
|    5      |         7     |  11.10 | 12.00  |      0      |    1     |         1         | 2019-05-06   |        1        | 2019-05-10 | 2019-04-05 12:27:10
```

I need to make a mysql query where I get the information of `"jobunique"`, `"jobtypeunique"`, `"joblat"`, `"joblng"` of all entrys which match the following conditions:

First, I need **no** entrys where `"jobpayed"` is `"0"`.

I need all entrys where `"jobbusiness"` is `"1"` and the `"jobstartdate"` is passed but the `"jobenddate"` isn´t. The current date musst be between the `"jobstartdate"` and the `"jobenddate"`.

I need all entrys where `"jobbusiness"` is `"0"`, "jobfixedstartdate" is `"0"` and "jobfixedenddate" is "0" like in line 3, where the `"jobcreatedtimestamp"` isn´t older than 60 days.

I need all entrys where `"jobbusiness"` is `"0"`, `"jobfixedstartdate"` is `"1"` and `"jobfixedenddate"` is `"0"` like in line 4, where the `"jobstartdate"` isn´t older than the current date.

I need all entrys where `"jobbusiness"` is `"0"`, `"jobfixedstartdate"` is `"1"` and `"jobfixedenddate"` is `"1"` like in line 5, where the `"jobenddate"` isn´t older than the current date.

I never did a join on a MySQL query, so I don't really know where to start...

Regards, Stefan

Comment: Create a complete SQL query for each of the rules/criteria you have set above.

Comment: I need a new car, but it doesn't mean I will get one.  I would recommend just asking us about _one_ query.  Learn what you can from that, and then move on to the next query.

Comment: You do **not** need joins as your query is all on the same single table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can sell you a new car if you wish? `;-)` Manual or Automatic?

Comment: I can drive stick, so I would prefer manaul :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please [come through to my Garage](https://toggl.com/developer-methods-infographic/)...

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hmm, that would be an easy way out :) - Okay, can you tell me by rule of thumb what would stress the Mysql-server more, one complex querry or 4 simple querrys in a row?

Comment: @stefanhalbeisen depends if you've set your DB up properly with the correct indexes and shards and the quantity of data to navigate through.....

Comment: @Martin :) if it is "alot" of entrys, like 30.000 rows and I have only an index on my unique id?

Comment: 30k is not a lot of rows. By a lot I mean several million. We are discussing a different question to what is posted here, you can research DB efficiency before posting another question on ths specific topic. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correct this query help you.

```
SELECT
    jobunique,
    jobtypeunique ,
    joblat ,
    joblng
FROM job
WHERE
    jobpayed != 0 
    AND 
    (
        jobbusiness = 1 AND jobstartdate > NOW() AND jobenddate <= NOW()
    ) OR
    ( 
        jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 0 AND jobfixedenddate = 0 AND jobcreatedtimestamp <= (NOW()-INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
    ) OR
    (
        jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 1 AND jobfixedenddate = 0 AND jobstartdate >= NOW()
    ) OR
    (
        jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 1 AND jobfixedenddate = 1 AND jobenddate >= NOW()
    )
```

My bests.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to the structure of this SQL? Code only answers are rarely actually helpful.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me alot to understand this thing :)

Comment: @Martin - I did not see your comment.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to solve this query

```
SELECT * FROM 
job
WHERE 
1= (CASE WHEN jobbusiness=1 AND (jobstartdate >= jobenddate AND NOW() >= jobstartdate) THEN 1
   CASE WHEN jobbusiness=0 AND jobfixedstartdate=0 AND jobfixedenddate=0 AND date_diff(NOW(),jobcreatedtimestamp)>60 THEN 1
   CASE WHEN jobbusiness=0 AND jobfixedstartdate=1 AND jobfixedenddate=0 AND jobstartdate>= NOW() THEN 1
   CASE WHEN jobbusiness=0 AND jobfixedstartdate=1 AND jobfixedenddate=1 AND jobenddate>=NOW()    THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to the structure of this SQL? Code only answers are rarely actually helpful.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me alot to understand this thing :)